# How to get last refrer Url in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have found problem in my code. I am working on facebook application. and May be facebook made some changes so I got struck. Everything was working fine till yesterday. But from today it's not working.

Issue that what i found is. Earlier I was managing last refer url for some task. But its format get changed. Now it's not working.

Last refer URL is

http://apps.facebook.com/mycurrentfollower/?session={%22session_key%22%3A%221fd7d4189b8eded157c4a173.0-100000086206090%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22100000086206090%22%2C%22expires%22%3A0%2C%22secret%22%3A%2226e9d307ff4038173e966d881faf0c97%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22194311980605862|1fd7d4189b8eded157c4a173.0-100000086206090|YmiFbTAucSZ-TvkCA6QZVUw4-8M%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%222c6a9973a4dd868744d712d919a2b937%22}

But when I am trying to fetch last refer url like

```
  Uri requesturl = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

I am only getting this Part

```
http://apps.facebook.com/mycurrentfollower/
```

And this is also my current URL.

How Can I get rest of url. Please let me know. I trried lot of thing but nothing is working.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are calling the wrong functions on the `Uri` class? I would call [`Uri.OriginalString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx), this should give all.

Answer (score 1):

hey i think this will help you

```
Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery
```